# Invalid syntax after for loop using pandas datagrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm getting an **invalid syntax -error** after a for-loop using lists and pandas dataframe.

The code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

pd_dataframe1 = pd.read_csv("file1.csv", sep="\t", low_memory=False)
pd_dataframe2 = pd.read_csv("file2.csv", sep="\t", low_memory=False)
pd_dataframe2 = pd_dataframe2.set_index([column0])

columns=["column1", "column2"]

my_list= pd_dataframe1["column1"].tolist()
result = []
for i in my_list:
  try:
    result.append(pd_dataframe2.loc[(i), {"column1","column2"}])
  except:
    pass
output = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=columns)
```

If I run the loop on its own, it works, and if I run the **"output = ..."** after that, it works. But if I try to run the whole code in one continuous stream, I get **"Syntax error: invalid syntax"** pointing at **"output = ..."**.

What am I doing wrong? How to get this working?

Comment: If you're typing this into interactive mode, you need a blank line after a multi-line statement.

Comment: I've tested this in interactive mode, but the code will be run in a cluster. I added blank lines, but it still gives the error.

Comment: Run what you posted, but with a single blank line after the `pass`, and see what happens.

Comment: (None of this is going to matter for whatever you're doing on the cluster unless you're doing something really weird.)

Comment: Single nor multiple blanks didn't work. I would like to know that this will work before putting it in the cluster, because the dataset (pd_dataframe1) I'm using has over 4 million rows (pd_dataframe2 has close to 40M), and only gives the results at the end of the loop. I need to see that the result will most likely be valid before committing to the run.

Comment: Ok, I tried this in non-interactive mode, and it does work. Thank you for your suggestions!